# How to set text color and add border in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to make the append inside tr / td. or just to make border like in the picture. + yellow text. How to do it please?

https://i.gyazo.com/562b6590756292ce40134f9bd1cb5ca6.png

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/7468/

```js
$(".aprovadas").append("COLOR_ME");
$(".aprovadas").append("<br>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aprovadas"></div>
```

Comment: `$(".aprovadas").css({"style":"value"})` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: You can use jQuery's `css()` method, but this isn't a great idea as it ties the styling and JS logic together. Instead define a class in CSS and use `addClass()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".aprovadas").css("border", "2px solid lightblue");
$(".aprovadas").css("display", "inline-block");
$(".aprovadas").css("color", "yellow");
```